# Previous console log change after assign new value in javascript sub object property. Help me

Tags: javascript, console, json

Recently I am facing problem with javascript sub object value assign. My sample code is

```
var user = {
        name: {
            fname: 'Apple'
        }
    };

console.log(user);
user.name.fname = 'Orange';
console.log(user);
```

So its console twice But, fname value always show Orange. But I want output will be Apple then Orange. How do i do that or actually what happened? Please Let me explain actually what going on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript logging object with mutating state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993144/javascript-logging-object-with-mutating-state) and [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var user = {
        name: {
            fname: 'Apple'
        }
    };

console.log(user.name.fname);
user.name.fname = 'Orange';
console.log(user.name.fname);
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I tried that and works fine. But I was afraid about object. Now its clear me and got a solution. Cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use console.dir(object) to print object

```
console.dir(user);
```

Don't need to use console.log(user.name.f);